# How do i create a system where a user can favourite/unfavourite individual courses on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to create a 'favourites' system where the user can click on a star in the top right of a button to add that course to their list of 'favourites'. Here is the HTML for said button (there are 6 of them and all 6 are the same):

```
<button class="divflexbuttonitem">
    <div class="libraryfaviconcontainer">
        <i class="libraryfavicon" onclick="toggleFavourite()"></i>
    </div>
</button>
```

And here is my (attempt at) JavaScript for the toggleFavourite() function:

```
function toggleFavourite() {
    console.log("Running toggleFavourite();");
    var favicon = document.getElementsByClassName("libraryfavicon");
    var faviconCount = favicon.length;
    var favArray = new Array();
    var favArrayString = favArray.toString();
    var i;

    for(i = 0; i < faviconCount; i++) {
        favArray.push(favicon[i].id);
    }

    alert(favArray.length);
    alert(favArrayString);

    let favourite = false;

    if (favicon[i].style.backgroundImage == 'url("libraryfavselected.png")') {
        favourite = true;
    }
    else if (favicon[i].style.backgroundImage == 'url("libraryfavunselected.png")') {
        favourite = false;
    }

    if (!favourite) {
        favicon[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url("libraryfavselected.png")';
        console.log("Added to Favourites");
    }
    else {
        favicon[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url("libraryfavunselected.png")';
        console.log("Removed from Favourites");
    }
}
```

I am trying to get all elements with a specific class name, add them to an array, and call them from an array to change the url of the 'favicon' of the specific favicon that was pressed. However, my code does not work whatsoever and i am lost as to how to correctly code it.

Comment: Welcome. What does not work exactly,what is the error you are getting? where does it stop? elaborate please on your question to make it more specific. Try to make it easier for people to answer, so they dont have to debug everything from the start if you can point them to a certain line already etc :) Also tell us about what do you want your JS code to do and where the wanted procedure currently fails.

Comment: This is a great time to begin familiarizing yourself with your browser's debugging tools.  In those tools you can observe any error messages on the console, you can step through the code line by line in the script debugger, etc.  When you do this, are there any error messages at all on the console?  When you debug, which is the first operation to produce an unexpected result?

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to structure this type of application, but here is some really simple code to get you started.

You can see that the `fav` class is toggled on and off when an item is clicked, and then we can get all the current favourites by querying all elements with the `fav` class.

```js
const toggleFavourite = (event) => {
  if (event.target){
         const clickTarget = event.target;
         clickTarget.classList.toggle('fav')
  }
}

//Example use, get all favs and attach the text as a new element
const getFavs = () => {
  const favs = document.querySelectorAll('.fav');
  const favContainer = document.querySelector('.favs')
  favContainer.innerHTML = "";
  for( let fav of favs){
    let newFav = document.createElement('div');
    newFav.textContent = fav.textContent;
    favContainer.appendChild(newFav)
  }
}
```

```css
.fav {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<i class="" onclick="toggleFavourite(event)">1</i>
<i class="" onclick="toggleFavourite(event)">2</i>
<i class="" onclick="toggleFavourite(event)">3</i>
<i class="" onclick="toggleFavourite(event)">4</i>
<i class="" onclick="toggleFavourite(event)">5</i>


<button id="getFavs" onclick="getFavs()">Get Favs</button>

<section class='favs'>
</section>
```